# ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('

Tags: solidity, truffle

[image]

The receive function shows an error while compiling in truffle.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public players;
    address public manager;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    

//Error Function

    receive() external payable{
        require(msg.value == 0.1 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function random() internal view returns (uint256) {
        return
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        block.difficulty,
                        block.timestamp,
                        players.length
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        require(players.length >= 3);

        uint256 r = random();
        address payable winner;

        uint256 index = r % players.length;

        winner = players[index];

        winner.transfer(getBalance());

        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

}
```

**ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('
receive() external payable{
^**

Comment: This contract is fine, no errors. Your issue comes from another place, please post the full compilation result.

Comment: @Kof I've added the compilation error to go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of solidity to compile the contract, `receive` is a keyword of the language that was added around 0.6.x.

https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/03/26/fallback-receive-split/

To use version `0.8.x` for instance, you first have to update your code -

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
```

In your truffle config file, you can specify the solidity version to use -

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.0"
    }
  }
```

See Truffle Configuration docs [here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/).

Comment: I changed my solidity version to 0.8.0 but when I check it with `truffle version` it still shows a solc version of 0.5.16. I reinstalled truffle but the version remains the same. Soo no luck..

Comment: Added how to set solc version to my answer

Comment: I already changed it  to 0.8.0 in config file. But now it shows `Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;`

I have reinstalled solc and truffle many times but the version still sows 0.5.16 for some reason.

Comment: That's because your code requires support of version `>=0.5.0` as defined in your 3rd line of code

Comment: I actually had an inner directory with a config file where I didn't update my truffle version. Works fine now, thanks!